# SSIS Package is not executing from SQL Agent Job

Tags: ssis, oledb, etl, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I am trying to create a scheduled job, which should be executed daily at 23:15 o'clock.

If I execute my package from Visual Studio it is working fine and it fills my Excel-files. But this is only working, when I do it manually.

If I execute my package by a scheduled job, I get the following errors:

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJN0.png)

I found out, that I have to install "AccessDatabaseEngine" (x32) and but nevertheless my problems have not been solved.

Do you have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: How are you creating connection in your SSIS package to EXCEL

Comment: 2 things to check. Can agent access the file location? Run agent in 32 bit mode (there's a check box on the GUI)

Comment: How can I test what locations the agent can access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have 32 bit checked in your advanced configuration in the steps
[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked my scheduled job for 32-bit-runtime configuration and that was missing. I started the job again and I get one less mistake than before^^

Comment: The fifth error message in the above picture has gone. The rest of them still remain...

Comment: Also set your project properties 64 bit runtime to false. I edited the above picture. Right click on the project name and go to properties.

Answer (score 1):

- It is easy to miss replacing local addresses like C:.. in your connections with network addresses when the job is ready to be scheduled. Sql Agent will need a UNC(network path) eg.
  \servername\folder\excelfile.xlsx
- Look at the Sql Server agent service running on the server and
  identify the account. Provide access to above network share to this
  account.